# Improve design movement on Snake game

Tags: c++

I am trying to improve my game development design and for now I have something like this:

```
class Movement {
private:
  Body b;    
public:
  move_up() {
    // catch the body head
    // add one snake character above head
    // catch the body tail
    // remove the tail character
  }
  move_down(){
    // catch the body head
    // add one snake character below head
    // catch the body tail
    // remove the tail character
  }
  move_left(){
    // catch the body head
    // add one snake character on left side of head
    // catch the body tail
    // remove the tail character
  }
  move_right(){
    // catch the body head
    // add one snake character on right side of head
    // catch the body tail
    // remove the tail character
  }
}
```

It is pretty ugly to see repetead pseudocode inside each move method. I would like to make this more generic but I don't know how to do it in C++. Any suggestions?

Comment: make a `move` function that takes an enum as parameter (indicating which way to go)?

Answer (score 1):

For a snake game, you probably want to handle this in two separate pieces.

One piece responds to keyboard input. All it does is record a new direction of travel based on the input key.

The other piece runs at predefined intervals. It:

1. checks for collision

   - and ends game if there is one
2. adds a character to the head of the snake in the current direction of travel
3. removes a character from the tail

   - (provided the snake didn't just eat a power button)
4. updates the score
5. and probably a few more things that don't occur to me right now

In particular, however, we don't want any of the second list to wait for input from the user. The second part just runs continuously, so the snake keeps moving even in the absence of input from the user.

Answer (score 0):

I've made Snake before, these are the steps used in my program to make Snake happen;

1. When the direction of the snake is changed, it must check it wasn't going in the 180°-rotated direction before, otherwise the current direction may not change.
2. The methods you described in your post must only contain what's needed to add one dot/pixel/character to the snake, next to the current position of the snake.
3. You need a list of all dots of the snake (containing x,y values).
4. On every move, you must, first of all make sure you're not crashing into yourself or into a wall, else you should die first.
5. On every move, if a move was succesfull, you must check if your current position (last move) contains food on that same position, if yes, add a score to the score variable and make sure you don't remove the oldest (x,y) of the snake's list.
   If not, you must remove that one.